aggfunc where I calculate mean by index first and then sum by column in python pivot table
I have a dataframe in Python like this and I need to build a pivot table that as aggfunc first calculates the mean of each column for each label and then sum all the mean values by column.
Dear community, any idea about how I could do that? I was thinking at 2 sequential pivot tables but this doesn't sound efficient.
thanks !

the result should be something like:


You shouldn't put data as an image. But here is the code you should use,
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

#  Calculate the mean for each label
mean_df = df.groupby("label").mean()

# Sum the mean values across the columns
totals = mean_df.sum()

# Display the result
result = pd.DataFrame([totals], index=["tot (mean a + mean b)"])
print(result)

